# Data mutation in Angular directive for d3 tree-based chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js, tree

I'm using a `d3` with the `d3.layout.tree()` layout to construct an SVG-based tree. I wrapped this d3 code into an angular directive and would like to re-render the tree every time the data changes. The data object is a parameter of the directive and gets passed in from outside of the directive. To do the update-on-data-change, the directive `$watch`es its data parameter and calls the tree's render method which does all the update/enter/remove.

So far for the theory. Unfortunately, `d3` stores some state information on the actual data object which would trigger the directive's `$watch` handler for the tree to be redrawn which ends up in an infinite loop.

Has anyone encountered such a problem before and what's a good way of getting around it? I could pass in a copy of the actual data object into the `d3`-rendering method, but that would wipe out the tree state information every time the tree data changes. The reason why the tree data gets changed is because new leaf/node information is loaded once the tree is expanded (initially all but the root node are collapsed), so I would really like to keep the tree's state information.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing anything about d3...

1. Deep copy Obj A to create Obj B
2. Pass Obj B to d3
3. Watch Obj A
4. When the watch is triggered, recursively iterate over Obj A and update object B. Any new nodes can be deep copied while existing nodes must be iterated over to check for d3 information to be updated.

This could be abstracted to a util function.